# What does "support" mean when it comes to SQL Server versions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

We are considering upgrading from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2019, but I just noticed on [this website](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) that the support end date for 2019 is 1/7/2025. If we do this upgrade, we would basically only have "support" for 2023-2024. This seems pretty short, so I wanted to ask what "support" means in the context of SQL Server.

Comment: Use the Microsoft references perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/end-of-support/sql-server-end-of-support-overview?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: As a note, support for SQL Server 2019 doesn't end in 2025, *Mainstream* support does. Extended support ends on 2030-01-08.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's [own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/end-of-support/sql-server-end-of-support-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) on end of life support explains how it works very clearly:

> Each version of SQL Server is backed by a minimum of 10 years support, which includes five years in mainstream support, and five years in extended support:
>
> - Mainstream support includes functional, performance, scalability and security updates.
> - Extended support includes only security updates.
>
> **End of support** (also sometimes known as end of life) indicates that a product has reached the end of its lifecycle, and servicing and support is no longer available for the product. For more information about the Microsoft Lifecycle, see [Microsoft Lifecycle Policy](https://support.microsoft.com/hub/4095338/microsoft-lifecycle-policy).

Tim's comments: So if you use SQL Server 2019, you should be entitled to 5 years of full support, until 2024, followed by 5 years of security updates and patches, until 2029.